# Why is vcvarsall.bat necessary while installing python module?

Tags: python

I saw this question throughout StackOverflow with  lots of answers. But its really painful to end up the day without having the problem solved. I am having issue installing modules with pip, easy_install and even from the source. when I try to install any python package using `pip install <some package>`, I get an error which is annoying:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarshall.bat
```

I googled the problem, despite lot of answers, nothing seemed to help really. I tried installing the package using `easy_install` but ended up with the same error message. I have two questions regarding this problem.

> Why do I need vcvarsall.bat for installing python package.?
>
> What do I need to do to avoid the problem. Please suggest something
>   that really  solves the problem in python 2.7.5, 64 bit windows 8 machine.

Comment: You might be better off installing precompiled packages on Windows - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is a good source

Answer (score 1):

This particular package you're trying to install includes C code that *needs to be compiled*. It's looking for `vcvarsall.bat` to set up the Visual C++ build environment.

Comment: thanks but how am supposed to.? I installed visual studio 2008 but still get the same error.